# How to compare value from radio button with specific value in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, radio-button

I'm trying to assign my radio button value with a specific value in Firebase. But when I run it, I did not get the output. The problem of the coding is here (snapshot.child("Allergy").child("None").getValue().equals(selectedRadioValue2)))) when I'm trying to assign the "None" value. Can anyone help?

```
   dr.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       Intent intent = getIntent();
       String selectedRadioValue1 = intent.getExtras().getString("SelectedValue1");
       String selectedRadioValue2 = intent.getExtras().getString("SelectedValue2");

       @Override
       public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
             if ((snapshot.child("Age").getValue().equals(selectedRadioValue1))&&((!snapshot.child("Allergy").getValue().equals(selectedRadioValue2))
                     || (snapshot.child("Allergy").child("None").getValue().equals(selectedRadioValue2))))


               {
                   String ingredient = snapshot.child("Ingredient").getValue().toString();
                   HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>();
                   al.add(ingredient);
                   hashSet.addAll(al);
                   al.clear();
                   al.addAll(hashSet);
                   Collections.sort(al);
                   ad.notifyDataSetChanged();

                   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                           Toast.makeText(result.this, "Category Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           String TempListViewClickedValue = al.get(position).toString();
                           Intent intent = new Intent (result.this,RecommendedFood.class);
                           intent.putExtra("1",selectedRadioValue1);
                           intent.putExtra("2",selectedRadioValue2);
                           intent.putExtra("RecommendedFood",TempListViewClickedValue);
                           startActivity(intent);
                       }
                   });


               }
           }
       }


       @Override
       public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

       }
   });
}



    }
```

This is my firebase

[image]

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: The coding part where I assigned the allergy value to None. I did not get the result. This part (snapshot.child("Allergy").child("None").getValue().equals(selectedRadioValue2))))

Comment: So it evaluates to false?

Comment: yes. It not only does not retrive the correct result but also crashing the app